# C++ new operator returning new unexpected -Dev-cpp

Tags: c++, pointers, null, new-operator

I have a C++ class classA where I dynamically create an object instance of custom class classB through operator `new`.

I have done this liretally hundreds of times successfull; however on this case the new operator is returning a NULL pointer, even though I have checked the values of the `this` pointer inside constructor and it is returning a non `null` pointer.

I have created a class duplicating a minimum working example reproducing the fault. However, in this case the operator `new` works as expected.

From what I understand, this must be due to memory allocation failure.

Does anyone have any suggestion about how to troubleshoot this, where to start from or what might be the causes of this mihaviour?

I would gladly post my whole code, but I don't want to bore anyone...

I hope somebody can help me.

Thnaks in advance for your time!

UPDATE: code as requested
For your convineince  the method below it where the proble is occuring. Variable _radice is NULL (unchanged after the assignment).

```
 template <class T>         
 void AlberoNArio<T>::inserisciRadice(tipoElemento elemento)
 {
  _radice==new NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>();
  cout<<endl<<_radice<<endl;
 }
```

**NodoAlberoNArioLista.h**

```
#ifndef _NODO_ALBERO_N_ARIO_LISTA_H
#define _NODO_ALBERO_N_ARIO_LISTA_H


template <class T>
class NodoAlberoNArioLista
{
public:

 typedef T tipoElemento;
 typedef NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>* posizione;

 tipoElemento _elemento;
 posizione _padre;



 NodoAlberoNArioLista();
 NodoAlberoNArioLista(tipoElemento, posizione);
 NodoAlberoNArioLista(NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>&);
 NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>& operator=(NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>&);

 static const posizione POSIZIONENULLA;
};


template <class T>
const typename NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>::posizione NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>::POSIZIONENULLA=0;


template<class T>
NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>::NodoAlberoNArioLista()
{_padre=0; cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<this<<endl<<endl<<endl;}

template<class T>
NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>::NodoAlberoNArioLista(tipoElemento elemento, posizione padre)//==NULL) da modificare accordingly **LEO**
{
_elemento=elemento;
_padre=padre;
cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<this<<endl<<endl<<endl;
}

template<class T>
NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>::NodoAlberoNArioLista(NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>& nodo)
{
 _elemento=nodo._elemento;
}

template<class T>
NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>& NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>::operator=(NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>& nodo)
{
 _elemento=nodo._elemento;

}

#endif
```

**AlberoNArioAstratto.h**

```
#ifndef _ALBERO_N_ARIO_ASTRATTO_H
#define _ALBERO_N_ARIO_ASTRATTO_H


#include <iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::istream;
using std::ostream;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::istringstream;

template <class T, class P>
class AlberoNArioAstratto
{
  public:
         typedef T tipoElemento;
         typedef P posizione;

          virtual bool vuoto() const = 0;

          virtual posizione radice() const = 0; 
          virtual void inserisciRadice(tipoElemento) = 0; 

};

         const string INIZIOFIGLITOKEN="[";
         const string FINEFIGLITOKEN="]";


         template <class T, class P>
         istream &operator>>(istream &is, AlberoNArioAstratto<T,P>& alberoNArio)
         { 

            typename AlberoNArioAstratto<T,P>::posizione tempPosizioneNodoAlbero;


            string rigaElemento;
            typename AlberoNArioAstratto<T,P>::tipoElemento tempElemento;



            getline(is, rigaElemento);
            istringstream iStringStream(rigaElemento);

            iStringStream >> tempElemento;  

            alberoNArio.inserisciRadice(tempElemento);
            tempPosizioneNodoAlbero=alberoNArio.radice();          


            getline(is, rigaElemento);

            return is;
         }

         template <class T, class P>
         ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const AlberoNArioAstratto<T,P>& alberoNArio)
         { 


           typename AlberoNArioAstratto<T,P>::posizione _tempRadice;

          typename AlberoNArioAstratto<T,P>::posizione tempPosizioneNodoAlbero;



          typename AlberoNArioAstratto<T,P>::tipoElemento tempElemento;




          if (alberoNArio.vuoto()==true)
          {return os;}

          _tempRadice=alberoNArio.radice();

          os<<tempElemento<<endl;

           return os;
         }


#endif
```

**AlberoNArio.h**

```
#ifndef _ALBERO_N_ARIO_LISTA_FIGLI_H
#define _ALBERO_N_ARIO_LISTA_FIGLI_H


#include "AlberoNArioAstratto.h"
#include "NodoAlberoNArioLista.h"


template <class T>
class AlberoNArio:public AlberoNArioAstratto<T, NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>* >
{
  public:
         typedef typename AlberoNArioAstratto<T, NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>* >::tipoElemento tipoElemento; 
         typedef typename AlberoNArioAstratto<T, NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>* >::posizione posizione;  

         AlberoNArio();
         AlberoNArio(const AlberoNArio&);

         ~AlberoNArio();


         void crea();

         bool vuoto() const;


         void inserisciRadice(tipoElemento);
         posizione radice() const;  

  private:

          static const posizione POSIZIONENULLA;
          posizione _radice;

};

          template <class T>
          const typename AlberoNArio<T>::posizione AlberoNArio<T>::POSIZIONENULLA=NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>::POSIZIONENULLA;

         //costruttori
         template <class T>         
         AlberoNArio<T>::AlberoNArio()
         {
          crea();
         }


         template <class T>         
         AlberoNArio<T>::AlberoNArio(const AlberoNArio<T>& alberoNArio)
         {

         }

         //distruttore
         template <class T>         
         AlberoNArio<T>::~AlberoNArio()
         {

         }


         template <class T>         
         void AlberoNArio<T>::crea()
         { _radice=POSIZIONENULLA; }

         template <class T>         
         bool AlberoNArio<T>::vuoto() const
         { return (_radice==POSIZIONENULLA); }


         template <class T>         
         void AlberoNArio<T>::inserisciRadice(tipoElemento elemento)
         {
          _radice==new NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>();//elemento,POSIZIONENULLA);
          cout<<endl<<_radice<<endl;
         }

         template <class T>                 
         typename AlberoNArio<T>::posizione AlberoNArio<T>::radice() const
         {

          return _radice;       
         }



#endif
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>


#include "AlberoNArio.h"
#include <fstream>



using namespace std;


typedef AlberoNArio<int> AlberoGenealogico;  
typedef AlberoGenealogico::posizione posizione;



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    AlberoGenealogico alberoGenealogico;

    string fileAlberoGenealogico="Integers.txt";   
    ifstream  filestreamAlberoGenealogico;   


    filestreamAlberoGenealogico.open(fileAlberoGenealogico.c_str(),ios::in);

    if(!filestreamAlberoGenealogico)
    {
     cout << "Impossibile aprire il file "<<fileAlberoGenealogico<<"."; //<< argv[1] << " for reading.\n";
     return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    filestreamAlberoGenealogico>> alberoGenealogico;

    cout<<endl<<alberoGenealogico<<endl;




    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Interger.txt**
    1
    2
    2
    3
    4
    5
    56

Comment: posting the code that does this will help

Comment: If your minimum working example reproduces the fault, how can it work as expected?

Comment: ok then, I will post in a few second.

Comment: mihaviour?  Is that a new contraction for misbehaviour?

Comment: What you understand is wrong.  Non-placement `new` _never_ returns a null pointer (unless the program has undefined behavior, or there is a bug elsewhere).

Comment: Didn't old VS versions return NULL? I wonder if the newed things ever get deleted.

Comment: _'From what I understand, this must be due to memory allocation failure.'_ If so, you usually should receive a `std::bad_alloc` exception, despite you have exceptions disabled in your environment.

Comment: @yurikilochek Ok I have posted the original code. Thanks

Comment: @Chris I created the minimum working examle with the aim of reproducing the fault and post it on SO, howerer the minimum working example is not affected by the fault. However I have posted a stripped down version of the orinal code as requested by  yuri kilochek which does have the fault.

Comment: @JamesKanze I have checked the C++ standard. New operator is supposed to return NULL oly is the nothrow constant is passed as a paramer in the call, which I am not. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/ However in my case it is indeed. I am using dev-cpp 4.9.9.2 default install.

Comment: @g-makulik Abslolutely. I agree with you. That's what it written all over the place. However in my cas a null pointer is returned. By the way, in the case of memory allocation failure, would the constructor the class being instantiated be called and executed successfully? In my case it is.

Comment: @geraldCelente _'would the constructor the class being instantiated be called and executed successfully? In my case it is.'_ No it shouldn't! That sounds like you're having UB somewhere or another strange side effect.

Comment: @geraldCelente I'd recommend the standard as reference; a new operator is not supposed to return a null pointer unless it is declared `nothrow()` (or `noexcept`, in C++11).  The page you cite speaks of several standard `operator new` functions, but the rules hold even for ones you write yourself.  (But I suppose that you were using a non-placement new.)  Unless you have a very old compiler, if `new` is returning a null pointer, you have undefined behavior in your code elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_radice==new NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>();`

should be

`_radice=new NodoAlberoNArioLista<T>();`

Comment: I am sure that fixes the problem. Thanks. I am so used to writing this type of code that I completely oversaw it. Thanks!

Comment: moverover, I was getting confused with a piece of code where the == is legit.